# Laravel WebSocket get SSL error message though Pusher

Tags: php, laravel-websockets

I'm using Websocket with SSL but if SSL has any issue I'm not able to findout out the exact issue. After Investigation "SecureServer.php" has a code which are emit the error but that error is not getting through pusher.

This is the code in **SecureServer.php**
[image]

With a valid SSL (certificate & private key) it's working fine. but I need to show an error when there is issue

can anyone help me on this to get this emitted error message through pusher?

**Versions:**

- Laravel: 9.52.4
- laravel-websockets: 1.13.2
- react/socket: 1.12.0
- pusher-js: 7.0.3

---

I've created a Custom WebSocketHandler sending pusher:error from OnError() function

```
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $connection, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof WebSocketException) {
            $connection->send(
                json_encode([
                    "event" => "pusher:error",
                    "data" => json_encode([
                        "socket_id" => $connection->socketId,
                        "activity_timeout" => 30,
                        "exception" => json_encode($exception->getPayload()),
                    ]),
                ])
            );
        }
    }
```

But didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe It's not an optimized solution

**Solution Steps:**

**Step 1:** Created another command `MyStartWebSocketServer.php` & copy all the content from `vendor/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/src/Console/StartWebSocketServer.php` And change command signature  from

```
websockets:serve
```

to

```
mywebsockets:serve
```

**Step 2:** Created another file under `/app` folder with a name `MyWebSocketServerFactory.php` & copy all content from `vendor/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/src/Server/WebSocketServerFactory.php`

**Step 3:** Goto Line Number 148 in `MyStartWebSocketServer.php` file & changed from

```
(new WebSocketServerFactory())
```

to

```
(new MyWebSocketServerFactory())
```

**Step 4:** Created another file under `/app` folder with a name `MySecureServer.php` & copy all content from `vendor/react/socket/src/SecureServer.php`

**Step 5:** Goto Line Number 79 in `MyWebSocketServerFactory.php` file & changed from

```
$socket = new SecureServer($socket, $this->loop, config('websockets.ssl'));
```

to

```
$socket = new MySecureServer($socket, $this->loop, config('websockets.ssl'));
```

**Step 6:** Goto line 200 in `MySecureServer.php` file and log the error when connection is not formed & show a proper message to user

```
$this->encryption->enable($connection)->then(
        function ($conn) use ($that) {
            $that->emit("connection", [$conn]);
        },
        function ($error) use ($that, $connection, $remote) {
            $error = new \RuntimeException("Connection from " . $remote . " failed during TLS handshake: " . $error->getMessage(), $error->getCode());

            // your code to send error message on UI

            $that->emit("error", [$error]);
            $connection->close();
        }
    );
```